# Drop down list and refering

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have a table of product names, wholesale and retail prices and capital gain based on one product in datasheet. In my primary sheet I have a drop down list of product names and next to that a cell that shows how many products I have.

What I need is a cell that checks the product name I chose from the drop list and calculates the capital gain for the set amount of products.

For example if I have product called pen that has capital gain of 0.5€ on the table on data sheet by choosing pen from the drop list and setting the amount of products to 100 I get 50€.

Thank beforehand :)

Answer (score 0):

```
=VLOOKUP(A1;C:D;2)*B1
```

A1 -> your dropdown cell (create it through Data -> Data Tools -> Data Validation -> List)

B1 -> Amount

C -> List of your products. Dropdown is refering to this list.

D -> Price of every product